# react pass children element from router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app setup by `dva 2.0.1`. In the `routers.js`, I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Switch, Route, IndexRoute } from 'dva/router';
import IndexPage from './routes/IndexPage'
import CountPage from './routes/CountPage'

function RouterConfig({ history }) {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={IndexPage}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/count" component={CountPage}/>
          <Route path="/statements" component={CountPage}/>
        </Switch>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default RouterConfig;
```

And in my `IndexPage`, I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'dva';
import styles from './IndexPage.css';
import { Layout } from 'antd'
import Header from '../components/Header'

const { Sider, Content, Footer } = Layout;

const IndexPage = (props) => {
  const { children, routes } = props;
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Header routes={routes}>header</Header>
      <Layout>
        <Sider>sider</Sider>
        <Content>{children || "No content"}</Content>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
}

IndexPage.propTypes = {
};

export default connect()(IndexPage);
```

However, the `console.log(props);`  gives `dispach`, `history`, etc. But `children` and `routes` are not in it.

What happened?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any child component on your `Index` component.

If you change this

```
<Route path="/" component={IndexPage}>
```

to this

```
<Route path="/" component={()=>(<IndexPage><p>This is a child component</p></IndexPage>)}>
```

you can see the child components inside your Index component.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. It does gives `children` in the prpos`. However, how can I replace `<p>...</p>` with my `CountPage` according to the path? i.e., how can I render the `IndexPage` without refresh the whole page?

Comment: Check [this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) for react-router. The logic is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

It turns that I was using `react-router@2` syntax and should be `react-router@4`.